# K-Mean for outlier detection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset which consists of 13 columns and about 10million rows. Part of my project is to use isolation forest, elliptic envelope and K-mean in order to detect and remove outliers. I'm trying to use K-mean but everytime I run the code, nothing happens to the csv file, am I doing something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ali97\\Desktop\\Project\\Database\\5-FINAL2\\Final After Simple Filtering.csv')
KMEAN = KMeans( n_clusters=100)
df['anomaly'] = KMEAN.fit_predict(df)
df = df[df['anomaly'] != -1]
del df['anomaly']
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ali97\\Desktop\\Project\\Database\\K TEST.csv', index=False)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? And to what does `df` prints after your filtering step?

Comment: You also seem to have posted [the same question a couple of hours ago which got closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471650/how-to-detect-anomaly-using-k-mean) due to lack of details. Please avoid that and provide more details.

Comment: KMeans is not going to magically detect anomalies. It is a clustering algorithm, so it clusters your data by assigning cluster labels to the data samples. Once you have clustered your data, then you can analyze the results to identify outliers. Read the SKLearn docs and see some examples of how it works, so you can figure it out and solve your homework assignment.

Comment: @petezurich It does not print out anything, just saves the new csv in my folder. I'll try to provide a sample of my dataframe.Also, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @mac13k I will read the SKLearn docs and example now, thank you. On a side note, I've never used python or any coding language before until last month,and I'm having a slightly hard time understanding everything. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: To what does `df["anomaly"]` print out before filtering?

Comment: @petezurich I will add a print and run the code again now, sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: No worries. I just reproduced your code with dummy data and it runs fine. I suspect your data yields all `-1`. If you can provide a data sample then this would help to find the problem.

Comment: @petezurich I'm verry sory, since my dataset very large, I'm just reading how to produce the first 100,000 rows for example, and then share it.

Comment: `df.sample(100_000).to_csv("sample_data.csv")`

Comment: @petezurich I have made a google drive link for you to downlaod the sample csv file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iB1qjnWQyvoKuN_Pa8Xk4BySzXVTwtUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will try your data and let you know.

Comment: Your code runs fine with the sample data. The problem has to be somewhere else. Have you tried to run your code on your side with the 100k sample? Have you tried to reduce `n_clusters` to e.g. the default of 8?

Comment: @petezurich I have tried 5,8,10 and 20 n_clusters. I did print out the anomly column and it appears most values have the value '6', so I'm running the code again to find the count number of '6' jsut to know if all rows have it or not.

Comment: @petezurich so I got  0 =1731204 , 3 =1690614 5    1467814 7    1218939 2     976513
6     815753
4     709495
9     578102
1     515690
8     345848

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208790/discussion-between-petezurich-and-ali-youssef).